# Building a custom component - crash on inflating when adding a listener

Tags: android

I am trying to add a listener to a custom component (Horizontal Number Picker) that I added to my app. This custom component is part of a `row_layout` used in a `RecyclerView`. When the app is trying to inflate the layout in the `onCreateViewHolder()` of the adapter of the `RecyclerView` I get an exception

> Error inflating class talkie.feedback.NumberPickerHorizontal.

But if I comment all the lines referencing the variable `mCallback` (in the code of the custom component), the app does no crash.

Here is my code:

**CUSTOM COMPONENT**

```
public class NumberPickerHorizontal extends LinearLayout
{
private OnNumberChangedListener listener;

public interface OnNumberChangedListener {
    void onNumberChanged(int value);
}

public void setOnNumberChangedListener(OnNumberChangedListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}

public NumberPickerHorizontal(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (MyCustomObjectListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement MyCustomObjectListener");
    }

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.number_picker_horizontal, this);

    Button btn_plus = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);
    Button btn_minus = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_minus);
    final EditText edit_text = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    final int nStart = 0, nEnd = 100;

    btn_minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int current = MySingleton.val(edit_text.getText().toString());
            if (current > nStart) {
                current -= 5;
                String s = "" + current;
                edit_text.setText(s);
                listener.onNumberChanged(current);
            }
        }
    });

    btn_minus.setOnTouchListener(new RepeatListener(400, 100, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // the code to execute repeatedly
            int current = MySingleton.val(edit_text.getText().toString());
            if (current > nStart) {
                current -= 5;
                String s = "" + current;
                edit_text.setText(s);
                listener.onNumberChanged(current);
            }
        }
    }));

    btn_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int current = MySingleton.val(edit_text.getText().toString());
            if (current < nEnd) {
                current += 5;
                String s = "" + current;
                edit_text.setText(s);
                listener.onNumberChanged(current);
            }
        }
    });

    btn_plus.setOnTouchListener(new RepeatListener(400, 100, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        // the code to execute repeatedly
            int current = MySingleton.val(edit_text.getText().toString());
            if (current < nEnd) {
                current += 5;
                String s = "" + current;
                edit_text.setText(s);
                listener.onNumberChanged(current);
            }
        }
    }));
}
}
```

**ADAPTER**

```
public class Recycler_View_Adapter extends   RecyclerView.Adapter <Recycler_View_Adapter.ViewHolder>implements
    NumberPickerHorizontal.MyCustomObjectListener
{

private final ArrayList<SettingsClass> usersArrayList;
List<SettingsClass> usersList = null;
private final int LayoutDetail;
Context context;
private final OnItemClickListener listener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}

public Recycler_View_Adapter(List<SettingsClass> UsersList, Context context, int layoutDetail,
                             OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;

    LayoutDetail = (layoutDetail == 0 ? R.layout.row_layout_simple :layoutDetail);

    usersList = UsersList;
    usersArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    usersArrayList.addAll(usersList);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //Inflate the layout, initialize the View Holder
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(LayoutDetail, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(position, usersList.get(position), listener);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //returns the number of elements the RecyclerView will display
    return usersList.size();
}

public void onNumberChanged(int value) {
    MySingleton.doMyToast(context, "the new value is=" + value);
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
public SettingsClass getItem(int position) {
    return usersList.get(position);
}

// Filter Class
public void filterA(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    MySingleton.printMyLog(2, "in Recycler_View_Adapter.Filter start {" + charText + "}");
    usersList.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        usersList.addAll(usersArrayList);
    }
    else
    {
        for (SettingsClass wp : usersArrayList)
        {
            MySingleton.printMyLog(3,"in Recycler_View_Adapter.Filter  {" + wp.name + "} [" + wp.name.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText) + "]");
            if (wp.name.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
                usersList.add(wp);
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    CardView cv;
    TextView description, rating, explanation;
    ImageView imageView;
    NumberPickerHorizontal numberPicker;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        rating = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        explanation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.explanation);

        numberPicker = (NumberPickerHorizontal) itemView.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_number_picker);
    }

    public void bind(final int position, final SettingsClass user, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        if (numberPicker != null)
           numberPicker.setOnNumberChangedListener(new NumberPickerHorizontal.OnNumberChangedListener() {
                        public void onNumberChanged(int value) {
                            MySingleton.printMyLog(1, "the new value is=" + value + "pos" + position);
                        }
                    });

        if (description != null && !MySingleton.empty(user.name))
            description.setText(user.name);

        if (rating != null && user.id > 0)
            rating.setText(String.format("%.2f", (float) (user.id / 20.0f)));

        if (imageView != null)
            MySingleton.displayPicture(user.iconFileName, imageView);

        if (explanation != null && !MySingleton.empty(user.categoryCode))
            explanation.setText(user.categoryCode);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onItemClick(position);
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT 1**

When I move the implementation code to the activity (in the above it is part of the adapter of `RecyclerView`which is used in a fragment) the exception is not fired. Is there a way to do the implementation in the fragment?

**EDIT 2**

In my layout I have several of the custom component, each belongs to another line of the list in the `RecyclerView`. How can I know, in the listener, which of these components called the listener? Since the components are inflated from the XML I have no control of the parameters passed to the constructor, which I thought can be a place where I can pass the line number in the `RecyclerView` that it belongs to and use each time I call the listener. For example, In my above code I would like to do `mCallback.onNumberChanged(current, position)`

**EDIT 3**

I managed to pass to the custom component the position within the list hadnled by the  `RecyclerView` by adding `setPosition()` method in the custom component and calling it from the `bind()` method of the adapter. The attached code was updated accordingly. Now, the last problem left is how to have the listener point to the fragment and not to the activity which is the parent of the fragment.

Comment: Does the Activity implement MyCustomObjectListener?

Comment: The implementation is done in a fragment. I added the code

Comment: Ignore the above comment. The answer to @Egor is as follows:This is done in the adapter - the code was included above (see onNumberChanged()). The adapter itself is used in a fragment.

Comment: @Egor, I was able to run it in the debugger and the exception is thrown when trying to get  mCallback = (MyCustomObjectListener) context in the constructior of NumberPickerHorizontal. So you are right that the problem is with the implementation of the listener, but I can see what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I pass a listener from my `RecyclerView` to my custom component and with the listener I can supply the value of the numberPicker and it's position in the list to the adapter. I updated the code above accordingly. Also, there is no need for the step in EDIT 3 because the adapter "knows" the position of the it's own row.